# How and when we have to use sentence construction 'was/were to have+ v3' to create sentences

Tags: verb-forms

What is the meaning of following sentences?

1. > The work was to have been complete today.

   (Can I also say: "The work was to have completed today" ? Or The work was to have been completed today" But why "been" has been used in above sentence?)
2. > If she were to have thought about it a bit more, she wouldn't have done that.

How and when we can use the sentence construction or structure **was/were to + have + past participle** or v3? Is it a causative form?

Comment: What does "v3" mean?

Comment: I think it's 3rd verb form or past participle. Am i right ?

Comment: @yubrajsharma You might be right but most English speakers have never heard of "v3". It's clearer to say "the past participle" if that's what you mean. The term "past participle" has a long history and is taught in elementary school throughout the English-speaking world.

Comment: As i'm not native speaker, there is more grammar problem in my  understanding and learning English. Could you please try answer my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These constructions indicate *hypothetical but not real* situations.

**Was to have**

*Was to have*, as in your first sentence describes an **action that was intended but never realised**. In the case of sentence 1, someone planned to have the work completed today, but it wasn't completed; either because whoever was supposed to do it chose to do something else, or because it took longer than expected.

This sentence is valid both for after the fact (we see now that it wasn't done) or as soon as the speaker realises that the planned action is impossible (we see now that we have two days' worth of work left to do; clearly we won't be done today).

Also, *was* here agrees with its subject for number in all circumstances. If you had a plural subject, you might say something like *We were to have finished the work today*. *Were to have* (and *were* in general in this use) is more complicated.

**Were to have**

*Were to have*, or rather *if* [subject] *were to have*, indicates a **hypothetical action that could have happened but now can't** (or at least can't happen with the described effect) because the situation has passed. In the case of sentence 2, she has done the thing already, and now even if she thinks about it a bit more, it won't prevent her from already having done the thing.

If we replace *were to have* with simply *were to*, we get a sentence about something that could potentially happen with the described effect, though it probably won't. Sentence 2, modified this way, would look like this:

> If she were to think about it a bit more, she wouldn't do that.

In this case, she still has the option to think about it a bit more and thus not do the thing. However, the phrasing with *were* suggests that we don't expect her to take this option - she can choose not to do the thing, but she probably will do it. This is in contrast with a simple *if*-statement without *were*, such as this:

> If she thinks about it a bit more, she won't do that.

With this sentence, we don't make any assumptions about whether or not she will think about it a bit more - she may or may not, we don't know.

There isn't much difference between *if... were to have* and simply *if... had*, in terms of how they describe a situation. These two sentences here describe exactly the same situation, in fact:

> If she were to have thought about it a bit more, she wouldn't have done that.
>
> If she had thought about it a bit more, she wouldn't have done that.

The difference here is one of formality and archaism - *were to have* is more archaic, and thus more formal, than simply *had*. *Were* here is one of the last remaining uses of English's subjunctive mood, a verb form used in Indo-European languages to indicate various kinds of unrealised situations. Many forms of colloquial speech have now lost the subjunctive entirely, and would prefer simply *had* over *were to have*.

This also means that it has strange plurality agreement sometimes, and may appear as *were* with singular or plural subjects - note that in your example, we have *if she were to have*, which otherwise would be wrong. Some speakers give it normal plurality agreement, though, and might say *if she was to have* here instead; I think I might use either *were* or *was* at random. The most formal and prescriptively 'correct' choice is *were to have*, but keep in mind that depending on your situation this may sound more stuck-up and snooty than you might intend - use it in writing, but probably don't say it to your friends. (You can replace simple *had* with *were to have* only in similar hypothetical situations with *if* - *if I had gone* and *if I were to have gone* are mostly the same, but *he got it done before I had gone* can't be transformed into **he got it done before I were to have gone*, which is ungrammatical and meaningless.)

These aren't causative forms, though they do look a lot like the causative form *have (someone) do (something)* - if sentence 1 was causative, it would look like *I had him complete the work today*, which would simply mean that I asked him to do the work today and he did it. You can, if you want, make a sentence that is both hypothetical and causative by combining the hypothetical *was to* and the hypothetical *have... do*, which comes out as something such as *I was to have had him complete the work today* (though that's really quite awkward) - meaning that I intended to make him complete the work today, but I haven't had the chance to ask him. You can tell the difference in that *have* as a causative will always be followed by a noun or pronoun, and then a verb in its base uninflected form; while *was to have* and such will always be followed directly by a verb in its past participial form.

To answer your other specific question - you can theoretically say *the work was to have completed today*, but this *complete* is in some ways a different verb from the *complete* used in *the work was to have been completed today*. There are, in effect, two separate words that both look like *complete*:

1. Transitive (takes a subject and an object), means *an agent puts in effort to finish an action*. An example is *I completed my project yesterday*.
2. Intransitive (takes only a subject), means *an action finishes on its own*. An example is *The download completed in the background.* (This sounds somewhat more formal/literary.)

There's a different connotation to sentences using the intransitive *complete* versus a passivised transitive *complete* (→ *be completed)*. The passivised transitive version still implies that someone somewhere is acting to finish this thing, and that if we left it alone it would never be done. The intransitive version implies that the action is getting closer to being done all on its own, and it would still get done whether or not anyone was working on it. *The work was to have been completed today* sounds like someone was supposed to have been working on it, and it got left undone and didn't get finished. *The work was to have completed today* sounds like whatever thing we set up and left to run took longer than it was meant to (or stopped partway through and needed setting up again).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but Could you please edit your answer as i've edited my question

Comment: @yubrajsharma Answer is updated!

Comment: One thing is still not addressed in your answer, can i say" the work was to have. . . . .. ..today, isn't addressed by answerer.

Comment: About 'been' isn't also not addressed

Comment: you're saying it's not causative but at the same time you're saying it's hypothetical causative. Oh , please clearly explain what you mean to say. Lastly i would like to ask you, can i use 'were to have' in the place of 'had'  while creating sentences ?

Comment: If addressed all my Problems,    I'll probably mark this answer as best

Comment: @yubrajsharma Ah, I did not notice those things (apologies!). Update is coming.

Comment: @yubrajsharma And done! Hopefully you can now tell that I'm making a distinction between hypothetical 'was to do/have done' and causative 'have (someone) do'.

Comment: You could be correct the way you'r answering my question about the transitive and intransative,  I'm Feeling very difficult to understand the meanings that the sentences imply, they are similar to me. How to distinguish the meaning. 

1. The work was to have been complete today.
2.The work was to have been completed today.
3. The work was to have completed today.

Comment: As I'm not a native of English, I tend to understand fairly simple  English writing, I'm  extremly sorry if i'm asking more

Comment: @yubrajsharma It's fine, I tend to write too complicatedly. 1 - Work was supposed to have already been done by today (probably would have finished yesterday). 2 - Work was supposed to finish today. 3 - Background process (not human labour) was supposed to finish today.

Comment: Oh i got it, Sir, I came to know that there is great difference between "was to have been' and was to have+past participle, You would also mean to say that they express intention or plan. Am I right ?

Comment: Anyway, sir, Your answer was absolutly helpfull, i have no words to explain it. I'm greatful to you.

Comment: Could you please try to put your answer on this  question too: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/328911/170668
 
I'm puzzled with it, i'm waiting for you